# iOS permission dialog displayed under active application

Tags: ios, objective-c, permissions

I have an app that works with CNContactStore so it needs some permission to access the contacts. The permission dialog is displayed automatically when first time launching the app, but problem is that the dialog is UNDER the launched application. I don't know why?

So you basically see white waiting application, waiting for the user action, but user doesn't see the dialog until he presses the home button.

Comment: **UNDER the launched application** , what do you mean by this??

Comment: How and when do you trigger the permission request: in the app delegate or the root view controller? In which callback method? Please add some code example.

Comment: Under the launched application mean what i said, it is under the launched application. You dont see the dialog until you press home button.

Comment: I access the CNContactStore in the viewDidLoad method of the controller (which is the first controller of the root tabbar controller)

Comment: Thx. This sure sounds like a platform bug, assuming that you don't to any crazy things in your app. I have no real solution but would try to postpone the permission popup, at least putting it in `viewDidAppear`, running it with delay (`Timer`), or even hooking it up to a button press.

Comment: ok thx i even now tried to put CNContactStore requestAccessForEntityType in the application delegate but no effect, i will try your idea thanks

Comment: i noticed that once i remove the contancts access method from viewDidLoad method, the app stops hanging (and has no access to contacts of course) but if i use the delay there as dr_barto suggested it works fine. thank you very much and thanks to all also